# MIPS swap two array elements

Tags: arrays, assembly, mips, swap

Say I have an array with 10 elements and assume the $s1 register is already loaded with the base address. How would I write a simple operation that will swap A[4] and A[9]?

So far I've come up with something which consists of using a temp register, but i'm not sure if its correct:

```
lw $t0, 4($s1) 
sw 4($s1), 9($s1)
sw 9($s1), $t0
```

Comment: What makes you think it is not correct?

Comment: This can be done w/o a temp register using exclusive-or operations.

Comment: @ScottHunter it cannot be done w/o a temp register in mips architecture

Comment: you can use xor swap although you shouldn't need to do that often

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are trying to swap items from an array of 32-bit integers, each item in the array occupies 4 bytes.
So you have to multiply each index by the element size to locate each item.
And your second instruction is invalid as `sw` it only receives one memory address (the destination operand).

So the easiest way would be to load both items and then save them with the data exchanged:

```
  lw $t0, 16($s1)
  lw $t1, 36($s1)
  sw $t0, 36($s1)
  sw $t1, 16($s1)
```